# Incorrect value of environment variable java_home

Tags: 14.04, environment-variables

I set my JAVA_HOME using the instructions given here - https://gist.github.com/senthil245/6093389
Basically, we download a jdk bin file, unpack it, move it to /usr/lib/jvm and then set the environment variable JAVA_HOME using `sudo vi /etc/environment`.

I entered and saved `JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_31"`
But, when I do `echo $JAVA_HOME`, I get `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java`

Why does this happen and how can I fix it ?

Comment: Did you run `source /etc/environment` after writing to `/etc/environment`?

Comment: @heemayl - no. why do i need to run that?

Comment: that will make sure the contents of the file gets executed on the current shell, so you will get the value set in there from the current shell..also a better option would be save the line in `~/.bashrc`...for now do `source /etc/environment` and now check.

Comment: `~/.bashrc` this is also new to me. I thought setting /etc/environment and export JAVA_HOME should be fine. This is confusing.

Comment: Ok, lets stay clean....after saving the line to `/etc/environment`, run `source /etc/environment`..now do `echo $JAVA_HOME` ..what do you see?

Comment: It is - /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_31/

Comment: Thats what you want..problem solved

Comment: Let me put this as an answer..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run:

```
source /etc/environment
```

so that the variables declared on the `/etc/environment` are available on the current shell and you will get the value of the variable set from the current shell. To make the variable available to all child processes of the shell, `export` it after `source`-ing:

```
export JAVA_HOME
```

Otherwise you have to logout from the current session and login again to have the variable as environment variable set in the `/etc/environment` file.

---

On the other hand, if you want to set this only for yourself, you can set it in `~/.bashrc` too by doing:

```
echo -e "\nexport JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_31" >> ~/.bashrc && source ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: Thanks. Actually, after I close window and then do echo java_home, it shows me the old jdk 7 which i removed long time ago with bad methods. But, if I do source /etc/environment before echo java_home, it shows me the correct jdk version 6. Why could this be happening ?

Comment: Save `JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_31"` in `~/.bashrc`, now if you close and then open a terminal you will get the new version printed as contents of `~/.bashrc` will always be executed when you open a new terminal..

Comment: I opened ~/.bashrc with `sudo vi ~/.bashrc`. the script looks very complicated. Where do put the java home in the script ?

Comment: @stack1: Run `echo -e "\nexport JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_31" >> ~/.bashrc && source ~/.bashrc`..now check....also remove that line from `/etc/environment`

Comment: so, basically, this is adding the java home at end of bashrc file ?

Comment: @stack1: Yes....

Comment: @stack1: You need to read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) very carefully..

Comment: Btw, I did not remove it from /etc/environment and it is working fine. If I don't remove, then will there be any problems ?

Comment: @stack1: There should not be any problem as both are the same. But you should remove that as its of no use now.

Comment: Just sourcing `/etc/environment` won't actually do anything useful, because while it will set `JAVA_HOME` in the current shell, it won't change the value of `JAVA_HOME` that is exported to anything else you run from the shell.  See my answer.

Comment: @mc0e Correct, it will become a shell variable....check the comments below the answer, actually I suggested OP to add it to `~/.bashrc` depending on the circumstances, although somehow I have forgotten to add all of these to my answer..thank you for finding this old one and knocking..I have edited the answer..

Answer (score 0):

After editing `JAVA_HOME` in `/etc/environment`, you should do:

```
source /etc/environment
export JAVA_HOME
```

If you only source the new value, that won't get exported to any subprocess run from your shell.